# How do I integrate this step function?

Tags: calculus

I need to integrate floor(x^2) from 0 to 2, with respect to x. The answer is supposed to give 5 - sqrt(2) - sqrt(3), but I can't get to that taking P = {0, 1, 2} as the partitions.

I am sorry, I can't use Latex.

Comment: Please don't punish people for not knowing Latex, there is no need when asking a quick question, especially for high schoolers

Comment: Your partition is not fine enough

Answer (score 3):

Floor only changes when the input gets to a new integer, so you must partition [0,2] into {[0,1),[1,sqrt2),[sqrt2,sqrt3),[sqrt3,2]}

This is because these are when x^2 Will become a new integer. Then doing the 4 integrals separately will give 0*1 + 1*(sqrt2-1) +  2*(sqrt3-sqrt2)+3*(2-sqrt3) = 5-sqrt2-sqrt3.